# php, mysql ( checking username and pass )

Tags: php, html, mysql

how to check username and password validation  by using Mysql without mysqli on xamp server ...for using mysql on my server shows the error ., so how can use mysql when connect the php on my server ..

Comment: Wow... Could you clarify your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it the old way? Here you go:

```
$conn = MySQL_Connect($hostname, $username, $password);
MySQL_Select_DB($Database, $conn);
$result = MySQL_Query($Query, $conn);
if(!$result)
    echo mysql_errno($conn) . ": " . mysql_error($conn);    
else
    return $result;
```